# Finding both characters and putting them in a new array

Tags: javascript

I've created a function that passes in a string and a character. The string is `saturday` and the character is `a`.

I want the result to be an array that contains all the index numbers of where the letter 'a' sits in `saturday`.

Then array ends up with only `[1]`. So it finds the first `a` sitting at the second index. I tested this by changing `saturday` to `soturday` and the console prints the array with `[6]`.

I want the result to be `[1, 6]`

I've tried putting the return result outside the next set of {} braces but no joy.

```js
const subLength = (str, cha) => {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if (str.charAt(i) === cha) {
      result.push(str.indexOf(cha));

      return result;
    }
  }

};
console.log(subLength('Saturday', 'a'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.

In your code the return is being executed as soon as a match is found. You want to return after you've checked every char - so I've moved it after the foreach.
`indexof` has a second parm, which defines the char to start looking from. If you omit it, you will get the index of the first match every time - which is not what you want.

```js
const subLength = (str, cha) => {
  let result = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] === cha) {
      result.push(str.indexOf(cha, i));
    }
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(subLength('Saturday', 'a'));
```

### Room for improvement

Since you are iterating over every char anyways, you can simply store every `i` where `str[i]` matches `cha`.

So optimized:

```js
const subLength = (str, cha) => {
  let result = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] === cha) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(subLength('Saturday', 'a'));
```

An even simpler version using regex:

```js
const subLength = (str, cha) => {
  return [...str.matchAll(new RegExp(cha, 'g'))].map(e => e.index);
};
console.log(subLength('Saturday', 'a'));
```

Answer (score 2):

2 small problems with your code

1. The return statement is in the for loop. The first time the loop hits that your loop will stop and the function will return. This is why you are only getting 1 result. Move the `return` outside the loop.
2. Once the above is fixed you will realize that your array will now return `[1, 1]`. This is because `str.indexOf(cha)` will always return `1` since it's returning the index of the first `a`. To fix this, you should be appending the index `i` to your array instead since it represents the index of the current char.

```js
const subLength = (str, cha) => {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if (str.charAt(i) === cha) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }

  return result;
};
console.log(subLength('Saturday', 'a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the `return result;` outside of the for loop?

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I tried that but the result then shows as [1,1].

Comment: For that see the answer of Andrew Lohr

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, if it is case-sensitive

```js
const subLength = (str, cha) => {
    const chaArr = str.split('');
    const result = [];
    chaArr.forEach((v, i) => {
        if (v === cha) result.push(i);
    })
    return result

};
console.log(subLength('Saturday', 'a'));
```

Comment: thanks that works. Do you mind if I ask what happens here: chaArr.forEach((v, i). Which value is v and which is i? so chaArr[0] is v and charArr[1] is i ?

Comment: the forEach method gives you access to the value/element (i called it here 'v'), the current index (i called it here 'i') and also possible a third argument -  the array which is iterated. So for each is kinda like a for of and for in loop in one

Comment: @DavidBoss in case you havent read it already